# Replacing a blank space between two capital letters with an underscore

Tags: r, regex, expression, stringr

I have characters in a string that look like this:

```
" A E 222;CMPSC 201 orCMPSC 202"
```

What I want to do is make is so that it looks like this:

```
" A_E_222;CMPSC_201 orCMPSC_202"
```

So far I tried the following code but it only puts an underscore in front or in back so I'm not sure what else to try.

```
str_replace_all(x, "([A-Z][:blank:][A-Z])", "\\1_")

str_replace_all(x, "([A-Z][:blank:][:digit:])", "([A-Z][:digit:])")
```

Comment: Maybe something like `(yada)[:blank:](yada)` replaced with `\\1_\\2`?

Comment: \\2 said it was out of bounds

Comment: I think akrun's way below is best (using lookahead and lookbehind), but the more direct fix to your code would be something like `gsub("([A-Z0-9])[[:blank:]]([A-Z0-9])", "\\1_\\2", x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds to match space that follows a capital letter (`(?<=[A-Z])`) and is followed by a capital letter or number (`(?=[A-Z0-9])`), replace it with `_`

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z0-9])", "_", v1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] " A_E_222;CMPSC_201 orCMPSC_202"
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's other text in the line and I can't have underscores under everything. I only specifically want underscores between the capital letters and the capital letter and numbers.

Comment: yeah i just did. my rep is so low so i had to wait like 5 minutes to accept it.